# SUM data over several sheets depending on condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I want to sum all values in a column on a number of sheets (a specific number of sheets, not all sheets. In this case the sheets "Employee...") depending on the content of another column "Uppdrag".

For each employee (represented by a worksheet) I want to sum the allocated time (per week) to a specific project on a summary sheet "Projekt". I want to place the sum of the allocated time to a project for all employees in one cell for each week.

I have tried the SUMIFS, INDEX, INDIRECT, named ranges and you name it without getting it to work. Perhaps someone with deeper skill than I have got some Ideas?

See attached images and maybe you understand what I want to accomplish.

Regards

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `SUMIFS` function should work. But I prefer use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUM((A2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4)*(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4);(A2=Sheet3!$A$2:$A$4)*(Sheet3!$B$2:$B$4)))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, allright! But how shall I do if the number of sheets is dynamic? I think that is my biggest problem.